# How do I get ReSharper to ignore certain categories when running all tests?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, nunit, resharper

I've got about 650 NUnit tests in my current solution in VS2008, but 40 of these are categorized either as "LongRunning" or "Integration". I do not want these to run every time I've done a change and run my test-suite (only when I specifically ask for it, and on the CI at set times).

Setting this up with TestDriven.Net is a cinch:
Tools -> Options -> TestDriven.Net -> Exclude tests in categories

I would like to use the nice UI that comes with ReSharper, though. I've not found any way of setting up ReSharper not to run certain categories.

Has anyone done this? Can it be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See:

> ReSharper | Options | Unit Testing | General | Skip tests from categories

[image]

Available in ReSharper 6, [see here](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/08/new-features-in-resharper-6-unit-test-runner/).

Answer (score 2):

I've created an issue in ReSharper's JIRA for it: [RSRP-140757](http://www.jetbrains.net/jira/browse/RSRP-140757)

Comment: Thanks! Let's hope they consider it worthwhile :)

Comment: Be sure to click on his link and vote the feature up.  More up votes = better chance of implementation.